# How to create and use and instance using guice in java play

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I am trying to use guice and I want to create a Singleton of random webservice client in Java Play 2.6

For now I have my WS client and it loads as a java play module. When I run the application, no problem, my client is able to use the java play Configuration (`com.typesafe.config.Config`), which is injected. But if I try to use my client anywhere else, I get an error saying  `No implementation for com.typesafe.config.Config was bound` .

Here is my (very simple) client :

```
import play.Logger;
import com.typesafe.config.Config;

@Singleton
public class MyClient {
    final Config config;

    @Inject
    public MyClient(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
        Logger.warn("constructor called")
        Logger.warn("Some config param:"+config.getString("some_param"))
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        Logger.warn("doSomething() called")
    }

}
```

My Module implementing Guice's AbstractModule :

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class MyClientModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override 
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MyClient.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

}
```

When I tell Play to use it as a module in `applicationf.conf`, it works (i get the `"Constructor called"` and the `"Some config param"` warning logs in the console):

```
play {
  modules {
    enabled += external.MyClientModule
  }
}
```

But If I try to call it from my `HomeController` :

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {
    public Result index() {
        Injector myClientInjector = Guice.createInjector(new MyClientModule());
        MyClient myClient = myClientInjector.getInstance(MyClient.class);
        return ok(views.html.index.render());
    }
}
```

then I get the following error :

```
[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for com.typesafe.config.Config was bound.
  while locating com.typesafe.config.Config
    for the 1st parameter of external.MyClient.<init>(MyClient.java:121)
  at external.MyClientModule.configure(MyClientModule.java:8)

1 error]
```

I'm pretty sure there are a few things wrong here, so what would be the correct way to bind it and then use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HomeController, use constructor injection :

```
@Inject
public HomeController (final MyClient myclient) {
    this.myclient = myclient;
}
```

You can annotate 1 constructor like this, so it needs to contain all the classes you want to inject. You can combine constructor and field injection, but that is not recommended.

Comment: Hello, just as I said earlier, please remove the part about `bind(MyClient.class).in(Singleton.class)`, which is not part of the solution. It works very well with `asEagerSingleton()`

Answer (score 0):

The asEagerSingleton() bind means that it's bound as fast as possible. In this case, Config is not bound yet, so it fails.

Use

```
bind(MyClient.class).in(Singleton.class)
```

which binds it as a singleton, when it's needed.

In the HomeController, use constructor injection :

```
@Inject
public HomeController (final MyClient myclient) {
    this.myclient = myclient;
}
```

You can annotate 1 constructor like this, so it needs to contain all the classes you want to inject. You can combine constructor and field injection, but that is not recommended.

Comment: Sadly, I get exactly the same problem when replacing `bind(MyClient.class).asEagerSingleton();` by `bind(MyClient.class).in(Singleton.class)` in `MyClientModule`.

Also, when using `asEAcgerSingleton()` the module is actually build at startup (if i log something it does appear in the console, I am able to read what is in the configuration).

I edited my post to explicitely tell that.

Comment: Why don't you @Inject MyClient in the controller constructor ?

\@Inject
public HomeController(MyClient myclient) {
    this.myclient = myclient
}

Comment: You can also inject it as a field, but I would recommend constructor injection in all cases.

Comment: I don't control the call of the Controller constructor, it's internal to play framework. But since calling the client in the Controller was just an example and I don't need to actually call it here, you might just have given me the answer to my problem. I'll try it and come back here to tell what's what. Thank you !

Comment: If you just create 1 constructor, annotated with @Inject, it will be fine. Even if you don't control the instantiation.

Comment: HOLY MILK IN A COCONUT, IT WORKS. Thank you very much, I know it's only because I basically learned about Guice yesterday but after 10 hours stuck on the same obviously trivial problem, it's a bit like an epiphany. If you post your comment (create a `HomeController` contructor in which I inject `MyClient`) as an answer (or edit your first answer) I can validate it as the asnwer. Thanks again !

Comment: I wanted to validate the answer but it still contain the bit about the `asEagerSingleton()` which is unneeded here. My edit explaining this got rejected so I cannot validate the answer while it stills implies that the `asEagerSingleton()` must be removed. Maybe just post a second Answer I can validate, in order to keep the history of the discussion.